# Creating directory for NLog log file on Azure

Tags: logging, azure, azure-web-roles, nlog, windows-server-2012

I'm writting application, which is running as `WebRole` on `IIS`. I'm using `NLog` for logging. One of `NLog` target is file.

I need this file with all recent events. Of course I have other targets, which let me easier access all log data I need. I have a problem with file target.

On my local PC, when I configure `NLog` to log to `C:\somedir1\somedir2\somedir3\logfile` `NLog` creates all needed dirs and log file. In Azure I need to manually create directories and change permission before `NLog` can write to logfile.

Is there any way to add some kind of task to project which would create all dirs I need? I think user on which `WebRole` is running has not enough permissions to create dir in `C:` drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add StartupTask to your webrole and run it with elevated privileges.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg456327.aspx